# How To Move Image To Point in SDL C++

Tags: c++, sdl

i try to move particle image to the point that the player will click on the screen.
i use this formula  from physics to calculate speed vector.

```
    float x = iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().x - iceBallParticle[i]>GetGoToX() ;
    float y = iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().y - iceBallParticle[i]->GetGoToY() ;
    float c = (x/y);
    float alpha = atan(c);

    //calculate the velocity x,y
    float yVel = (speedOfMoveSkill * cos(alpha)) ; 
    float xVel = (speedOfMoveSkill * sin(alpha)) ;

        //Move Left
        if(iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().x > iceBallParticle[i]->GetGoToX())
            //move the object
            iceBallParticle[i]->SetCurrentLocation(iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().x - xVel , iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().y);
. . . more moves direction down here.
```

GoTo is where the player clicked and the current location is where the particle shot from.
i think the problame is becuz he print the image by int and when i send it to print he miss the number after the point x.xxxx

```
  _______
 /
/
```

he go up and then straight, and i want him to go straight to the point

```
  /
 /
/
```

how i can to fix it?

Comment: Note that `sin` usually is the y-axis and `cos` is the x-axis.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is the position where the user clicks on the screen? Or what do you mean by "will click"? You mean in the future? How should you know that?

Comment: i mena: when i point with my cursor and click, the ice ball won't go in a straight line . it moves in a little curvy line.

Comment: Your question still stays somewhat unclear. Where is that code executed? How often is it executed? Where do you set `GoTo`? Is that all code? Why do you have only the "Move left" case there, what about the other cases? Please add the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand the question correctly.

One error is probably how you calculate `alpha`. You miss the sign of `x`/`y` by doing it that way. There is [`atan2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) to overcome this problem. It's just:

```
float alpha = atan2(y, x);
```

But you don't need to calculate `alpha` at all. An easier solution would be:

```
float dist = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
if(dist == 0) return; // exit here to avoid div-by-zero errors.
                      // also, we are already at our point

float yVel = (speedOfMoveSkill * x / dist) ; 
float xVel = (speedOfMoveSkill * y / dist) ;
```

(Note that you have switched `sin`/`cos` for `xVel`/`yVel`. `sin` is always the `y`-axis, `cos` the `x`-axis.)

I think you have another error in the "move the object" code. You missed `yVel` there.

This might be the code you want:

```
//move the object
iceBallParticle[i]->SetCurrentLocation(
  iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().x - xVel,
  iceBallParticle[i]->GetCurrentLocation().y - yVel);
```

I don't really see why you have the "Move Left" check there. It should not be there.

(Btw., it is more common to calculate `GoTo - GetCurLoc`. Then you have the velocity with the right sign and you normally add the velocity, not subtract it.)